# Qt Button Handling Advice

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have come to the point where I am tired of how I am handling user input in Qt (namely `QPushButton` presses) and I am looking for advice on the best method in which to handle these events.

Below is an example of what I am currently doing:

**MyClass.h**

```
class MyClass : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:

    ...

    QPushButton* getButtonA( );
    QPushButton* getButtonB( );

public slots:

    void buttonAPressed( );
    void buttonBPressed( );

private:

    ...

};
```

**main.cpp**

```
int main( int argc, char* argv[ ] )
{
    QApplication a( argc, argv );
    MyClass w;

    w.show( );

    QObject::connect( w.getButtonA( ), SIGNAL( clicked( ) ), &w, SLOT( buttonAPressed( ) ) );
    QObject::connect( w.getButtonB( ), SIGNAL( clicked( ) ), &w, SLOT ( buttonBPressed( ) ) );

    return a.exec( );
}
```

It works fine but I just feel that there must be a better/more elegant way than this, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are actually using the standard way of handling button presses in Qt. The only other way that I'm aware of is by having `MyClass` be an event filter for the buttons, that seems like overkill in this case.

The only change I would make to your code is to put the signal -> slot connections in `MyClass` itself. In this example, I'll assume that you want to set them up in the constructor, which would look like this:

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    QObject::connect( w.getButtonA( ), SIGNAL( clicked( ) ), &w, SLOT( buttonAPressed( ) ) );
    QObject::connect( w.getButtonB( ), SIGNAL( clicked( ) ), &w, SLOT( buttonBPressed( ) ) );
}
```

This keeps the connections out of the main method and groups them where they should be, which is in the class that contains the buttons that emit the signals.

Answer (score 4):

I'm guessing that you are designing the UI with Designer. Suppose you have a button named `pushButtonStart` for your `MyClass` class. Then you can place the connections inside `MyClass`'s constructor as [Matt Rogers states](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6950826/qt-button-handling-advice/6951066#6951066):

```
MyClass::MyClass()
{
    connect(ui->pushButtonStart, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(startPressed());
}
```

However, you can further simplify this technique of handling slots for signals emitted from UI controls. The above `connect()` call is not required if you define a function with the following specific way:

**MyClass.h**

```
MyClass
{
...

public slots:
    void on_pushButtonStart_clicked();

...
};
```

**MyClass.cpp**

```
MyClass::on_pushButtonStart_clicked()
{
    // code goes for pushButtonStart's clicked signal
}
```

The name of the function has to be very specific:

1. It must start with `on_`.
2. Then there should be the name of the control: `pushButtonStart`.
3. There there should be an underscore followed by the name of the signal: `_clicked`.

Qt magic. Qt automatically connect `pushButtonStart`'s `clicked` signal with `on_pushButtonStart_clicked` slot. You don't need to specify the connection separately.

Comment: I always forget about the autoconnect thing - for two reasons. The syntax is ugly :) and it didn't exist until Qt 4 and I started on Qt 3.

Comment: @matt rogers: it is handy in even a moderately large project as the constructor is already full of `connects()`s and there also may be other codes. i agree that the syntax is a little ugly but the naming scheme makes sense to me.